# Is it possible to add a calculated hyperlink in a django REST serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this serializer that represents content abstract where I would like to add an hyperlink field that is not in the model, but calculated by the framework linked to the ContentsSerializer.

```
class ContentsAbstractSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    content_url = ???
    class Meta:
        model = Contents
        fields = ('content_url','content_id','content_title', 'content_abstract','start_date','stop_date','last_date','content_status','version')

class ContentsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    categories = CategoriesContentsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Contents
        fields = ('content_id','content_title', 'content_abstract', 'content_body','start_date','stop_date','last_date','content_status','version','sections', 'images','attaches','categories')
```

I would like to have a result like this:

```
{
    "content_url":"http://mysite/Content/125",
    "content_id": 125,
    "content_title": "this is the title",
    "content_abstract": "This is the abstract",
    "start_date": "2005-01-12",
    "stop_date": "3000-01-12",
    "last_date": "2019-02-27T09:40:38Z",
    "content_status": "PUBLISHED",
    "version": 0
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that instead of define your own custom field you should use the manually specify the view_name for each nested resource as part of `extra_kwargs`.

I think that you simply could do something like that:

```
class ContentsAbstractSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contents
        fields = ('content_url','content_id','content_title', 'content_abstract','start_date','stop_date','last_date','content_status','version')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'content_url': {'view_name': 'name_of_your_detail_view'},
        }
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "content_url":"http://mysite/Content/125",
    "content_id": 125,
    ....
},
```

> **The Resource**: ['HyperlinkedModelSerializer' with custom nested
>   'view_name's does not work in combination with
>   'depth'](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4854)
>
> **Oficial Resource**: [How hyperlinked views are determined](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined)

Comment: It's not clear for me what is 'name_of_your_detail_view', in the Official resource I find: "... You can override a URL field view name and lookup field by using either, or both of, the view_name and lookup_field". in url.py I have router.register(r'contents', views.ContentsViewSet) and I suppose to need to configure content_url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="contents-detail"), I tried also view_name="contents" but I receive the error "Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name ...". Without content_url field it works.

Comment: Could you put your views with the register on urls.py in the post ? And I will tell you what is your view name. :)

Comment: urls.py: router.register(r'contentsAbstract', views.PtvContentsViewSet)
router.register(r'contents', views.PtvContentsWithAttributesViewSet)

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]

Comment: I think that it is `contents_detail` otherwiese if you invoke a 404 on your web page you will see all possible urls with their names.
Something like `http://mysite/tests/0000`